# HTML not calling external JS file

Tags: javascript, html

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="adlocationverify.js"></script>
        <!--other script and also external css included over here-->
    </head>

<body>
    <form>
        Sales Rep: <input type="text" name="salesrep" required><br>
        Customer Name: <input type="text" name="customer" required><br>
        Target URL: <input type="text" name="url1" required><br>
        Target URL: <input type="text" name="url2"><br>
        Target URL: <input type="text" name="url3"><br>
        Number of Impressions: <input type="number" name="impressions" min="100000" required><br>
        Start Date: <input type="date" name="startdate" required><br>
        End Date: <input type="date" name="enddate" required><br>
        Geo Target (Optional): <input type="text" name="geo"><br>
        Technologies (Optional): <input type="text" name="tags"><br>
        Ad Locations: <input type="checkbox" name="top"> Top Leaderboard <input type="checkbox" name="middle"> Middle Leaderboard <input type="checkbox" name="sidebar"> Sidebar<br>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" onClick="validateadlocation()">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

JS:

```
<script>
function validateadlocation()
{
    var checkboxs=document.getElementsByName("top middle sidebar");
    var okay=false;
    for(var i=0,l=checkboxs.length;i<l;i++)
    {
        if(checkboxs[i].checked)
        {
            okay=true;
        }
    }
    if(okay)alert("Thank you for checking a checkbox");
    else alert("Please check a checkbox");
}
</script>
```

The javascript works when inline with the HTML but not working when trying to call it from an external file.

Comment: Do you get an error in the console when requesting it as an external resource?

Comment: presumably the path is incorrect

Comment: The js file shouldn't contain `<script></script>` tags

Comment: I'd be **extremely** surprised if that script actually worked under any circumstances.

Comment: @Pointy Oh, it's doesn't work. Still testing it out.

Comment: @LoïcFaure-Lacroix That was the answer! Go ahead and answer the question and I'll accept it.

Comment: The `.getElementsByName()` function only expects one name at a time. You'll have to fetch each checkbox element separately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The js file shouldn't contain `<script>` and `</script>` tags. Tags should be only included in the html file.

Answer (score 1):

If you call the JS from an external file, you need to remove the **<SCRIPT></SCRIPT>** tags, otherwise you'll get an error.

Your js file must contain only the Javascript code:

```
function validateadlocation()
{
    var checkboxs=document.getElementsByName("location");
    var okay=false;
    for(var i=0,l=checkboxs.length;i<l;i++)
    {
        if(checkboxs[i].checked)
        {
            okay=true;
        }
    }
    if(okay)alert("Thank you for checking a checkbox");
    else alert("Please check a checkbox");
}
```